# Как сделать так,чтобы round() не округлял последнюю цифру? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, round

Например, у меня есть число `1.66666666666`.

Мне нужно округлить его до **5**-ого знака после запятой без округления последнего, чтобы конечный результат выглядел не так: `1,66667`, а так: `1,66666`!

(Интересует не конкретный случай,а все возможные, с любым количеством знаков после запятой.)

Comment: `int(x * 10**5) / 10**5`

Comment: Нет,это понятно и логично,мне нужно для любого количества знаков после запятой.

Comment: Ну замените 5 на любое нужное вам число

Comment: Ну вместо пяти в степени и используйте нужное число знаков: `def f(x, k): return int(x * 10**k) / 10**k`

Comment: Так как я буду знать,какое число будет введено с клавиатуры,чтобы возвести в ту или иную степень?))

Comment: у вас странные понятия об округлении :)

Comment: Ладно,тогда в другом вопрос,как сделать так,чтобы программа обрубала число до нужных мне знаков?

Comment: Ну какое будет введено, такое и используйте. Вы же не в воздух введенные числа считываете, а в переменные.

Comment: Так ввожу не я,а пользователь))

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Splake задача непонятна, вы хотите чтобы программа магическим образом прочитала мысли пользователя?

Comment: Если это число нужно только вывести куда-то, то `format` вам в помощь.

Comment: Задача в том,чтобы последний знак после запятой никогда не округлялся(вне зависимости от того,какое будет число)

Comment: @Splake тогда просто ничего не округляйте, и последний знак гарантированно останется нетронутым

Comment: Гениально!!! xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как вариант:

```
n = 1.66666666666

n1, n2 = str(n).split('.')

print(float(f'{n1}.{n2[:5]}'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться форматированием - преобразуйте число в строку, но используйте на один знак после запятой больше чем вам нужно и обрубите последний символ:

```
num = 1.66666666666

num_str = f"{num:.6f}"[:-1]
```

результат:

```
In [81]: num_str
Out[81]: '1.66666'
```

**NOTE:** но более правильно сделать так, как посоветовал @EzikBro в первом комментарии.